# Prove Tensor-hom adjunction via Hom-set definition

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products, adjoint-functors

I am trying to learn some basics of category theory, precisely Adjunction, but I've encountered some difficulties trying to prove such a statement.

So, I want to prove that tensor product $- \otimes X$ and Hom-functor $\textrm{Hom}(X,-)$ form an adjoint pair. Using the definition, that means that I want to prove that $\textrm{Hom}(Y \otimes X, Z) \cong \textrm{Hom}(Y, \textrm{Hom}(X, Z))$, and iso is natural in both $Y$ and $Z$.

I am not sure if there indeed is some general proof. If there is, any help is welcome.

Something I saw as similar was that $\mathcal{L} (X; \mathcal{L}(X;Y)) \cong \mathcal{L}(X,X; Y)$, where $\mathcal{L}(X;Y)$ is space of linear maps from $X$ to $Y$. If this is such a thing, how to see the required naturality (from the definition of adjunction)? Why $\otimes$ instead of $\times$?

Comment: The reason it's a tensor product is roughly that the RHS can be written as the bilinear maps from $X \times Y$ to $Z$ while the LHS are linear maps from the tensor product. Tensor product satisfy a universal property with respect to bilinear maps in the sense that there exists a bilinear map $f: X \times Y \to X \otimes Y$ such that for any linear map $g: X \times Y \to Z$ there exists a linear map $\hat g : X \otimes Y \to Z$ such that $g = \hat g f$. It's this universality that makes the tensor product special in the way needed to untangle the hom sets.

Comment: As to the proof, I recall learning of it from Weibel's text on homological algebra. It's presented pretty cleanly there in sufficient generality. It's not something I would expect a student to produce on their own in full their first time through the subject.

Comment: What is $\mathcal{L}(X,X; Y)$? And in which category do you consider tensor product and Hom? Vector spaces, $R$-modules?

Answer (score 3):

The following will work out the details in Brevan's comments:

I assume you are working on the category of vector spaces. Recall that by the universal property of tensor products there is a canonical (i.e., functorial with respect to all three variables) bijection
$$\hom(Y\otimes X,Z)\simeq\mathrm{Bil}(Y\times X,Z),$$
where $\mathrm{Bil}(Y\times X,Z)$ is the set of bilinear maps $Y\times X\to Z$.

Moreover, there is a canonical bijection
$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Bil}(Y\times X,Z)&\simeq \hom(Y,\hom(X,Z))\\
f&\mapsto (y\mapsto (x\mapsto f(y,x)))\\
((y,x)\mapsto g_y(x))&\leftarrow (y\mapsto g_y).
\end{align*}$$
I leave it to you to check the maps are well-defined and that they are inverses of each other.

Comment: What if it's not categories of vector spaces? Is such correct if these are elements of an arbitrary category?

Comment: You need a category which has the notion of a tensor product and hom.